# Reading property from a class member

Tags: delphi, properties, delphi-xe2

Why doesn't the following simple type definition compile?

```
type
  SomeType = class(TObject)
    ID: Cardinal;
  end;

  AnotherType = class(TObject)
    Some: SomeType;
    property ID: Cardinal read Some.ID;  // E2467
  end;
```

It gives [E2467 Record or object type required](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2467_Record_or_object_type_required_%28Delphi%29), *this occurs when trying to access a property from a variable that is not a record or object.*

But `Some` is an object, right? Is this a compiler bug (I'm using the latest XE2)? If this is expected behavior, what's the proper way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I guess "object type" here means the old school `object` (`SomeType = object`), not a class (`class(TObject)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property accessors must be either direct data members or direct methods of the same class that the property belongs to.

Try:

```
 AnotherType = class(TObject)
    function GetId: cardinal;
    property ID: Cardinal read GetId; 
 end;
```

The error message pretty much says it all. "Some.ID" is not a record or object. It is a data member of a data member - different thing.